# uint8 data to uint32 bits in EMBEDDED c

Tags: c, embedded, bit-manipulation

I am getting the input data from my microcontroller over uint8 data the are transmitted as 0xff, 0x2a.... the the two bits are subsequntly high and low values.
I need to convert this to uint_32 var where i can use memcpy

example

```
1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23
```

if this are the VALUES that are transferred how i can get them all in a single uint32 variable, with this below approach i can just get the last two bits which is just 23 and not the entire

```c
void Func(const uint8_t * data){
    uint32_t msgh =0;
    uint32_t msgl=0;
    uint32_t datah =0;
    uint32_t datal=0;

    for(int i= 0; i<dlc;i++){
        msgh=*data >> 4;
        msgl=*data & 0x0f;
        // printf("DATA %x%x",msgh,msgl);  
        memcpy(&datah, &msgh, 4);
        memcpy(&datal, &msgl, 4);
        // printf("msgl=%x\n",msgl);           
        data++;
    }
    printf("DATA%x%x",datah,datal);
}
```

Comment: Why do you copy a `uint32_t` local variable into another `uint32_t` local variable ?

Comment: Also, please explain more clearly what you want to do.

Comment: and how is it specific to embedded development ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I'd consider the intention pretty clear, converting four bytes stored in an `uint8_t` array into a single `uint32_t` value, though admittedly the (miserably failed – sorry, user20156410…) attempt hides that quite a bit again.

Comment: Hm... Just noticing: You are providing **8(!)** hexadecimal byte values in your example, sufficient for **2(!)** `uint32_t` values – do you only want to extract a specific four-byte subset of?

Comment: No I think he wants to separate the 4 most significant bits and the 4 least significant bits in every byte

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Hm... Never thought of this variant. Pretty strange protocol then – or maybe pretty strange usage of the data, but who knows. Maybe even an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)???

Comment: "the the two bits are subsequntly high and low values" What two bits? What are you even talking about? More importantly, what is your network endianess? Without knowing it, this question cannot be answered (which as usual will not stop people from trying to...). Also you need to clarify if this is C or C++, it can't be both at once. Is `Func` a C++ constructor or a syntax error?

Comment: Yes I need to seperate 4 MSB and 4 LSB in every byte

Comment: Please modify your sample data to `01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef` – this allows to identify every nibble individually – and add the desired result, e.g. `ec a8 64 20` and `fd b9 75 31`, which would correspond to little endian incoming data. Otherwise your question remains unclear.

Comment: *'[...] single uint32_t variable [...]'* – well, no, you need *two* of these!

Comment: *'Yes I need to seperate 4 MSB and 4 LSB in every byte'* – please don't just leave in a comment, add this information to the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to `memcpy`ing all this stuff – extracting the high and low nibbles of the bytes can be done as follows:

```
uint32_t high = 0;
uint32_t low  = 0;
unsigned int offset = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    high |= ((uint32_t)(*data) >> 4)   << offset;
    low  |= ((uint32_t)(*data) & 0x0f) << offset;
    offset += 4;
    ++data;
}
```

Note how you need to shift the offsets such that the nibbles get at their right positions within their respective 32-bit values.

Note, too that this assumes *little endian byte order* of transferred data (the byte order must be known and fix as part of the protocol definition for communication!).

Big endian order slightly differs:

```
uint32_t high = 0;
uint32_t low  = 0;
unsigned int offset = 32;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    offset -= 4;
    high |= (uint32_t)(*data >> 4)   << offset;
    low  |= (uint32_t)(*data & 0x0f) << offset;
    ++data;
}
```

(Well, could have started with 28 as well and subtracted 4 after nibble extraction, analogously to LE variant – this variant reflects my personal preference for constants of powers of two – number of operations doesn't differ anyway…).

Finally note that you might prefer to separate conversion and outputting into separate functions to achieve better reusability, e.g. like

```
void extract(uint8_t const* data, uint32_t* high, uint32_t* low)
{
    // assign to *high and *low analogously to above
}
// assuming C code; if C++, prefer references:
void extract(uint8_t const* data, uint32_t& high, uint32_t& low);


// or alternatively:

typedef struct
{
    uint32_t high;
    uint32-t low;
} NibblesCombined;

NibblesCombined extract(uint8_t const* data)
{
    // assign to the members of the struct analogously to above
}
// again assuming C; C++ could optionally return a std::pair instead!
```

Comment: Where did you learn the network endianess (array indices)? Did you just take a guess?

Comment: @Lundin Note that the answer *assumes* LE and tells what to do for BE instead, if need be – never thought of the nibbles, though, thus the edit, as answer was written before this option arose in the comments...

Comment: Hey @Aconcagua,
Thank you for the reply I have tried this approach but for
 example if this this the bit value that i need to get and in this order 
        5C 5D 5E 5F 60 61 62 63
with the approach that you shared earlier i get 
      5f5e5d5c and not the remaing bits 
Can you please guide me with this

Comment: The question is perfectly unclear and not just regarding endianess...

Comment: As a side note, these should be `((uint32_t)*data >> 4)`. Never shift (promoted) sign types.

Comment: @user20156410 Using your example data `1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23`: Part before edit should give you `1F 1E 1D 1C ` (or from at an appropriate offset, if need be), after edit  – `22 22 11 11` and `32 10 FE DC` or `11 11 22 22` and `CD EF 01 23` if you apply the BE variant.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the hint to signed shift – fully aware of, have been inattendent... As mentioned, never thought of the second option before posting the answer, now covering in the edit. Cannot imagine yet another (meaningful) option – can *you*? If so, finally going to delete...